# jquery Trent Richardson date time picker doesnt work on windows 8 IE10

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I am using [Trent Richardson date time picker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/). It works good on all the OS and browsers except on windows 8 IE 10. Even in Windows 7 IE 10 it works fine. In windows 8, IE 10 i could see the datetime picker is scrambled when i toggle between different dates. I see some scrambled texts instead of numbers. Below are the screenshots of such layouts. Did any one face this issue. My time picker is used in production now and causing lot of troubles because of this.Please help me to find a fix for this issue

[image: datetimepicker1]

[image: datetimepicker2]

Here is the code am using. I have a text box

```
  <input type=text name="marketDate" id="marketDate" value="" />
```

to which i am associating the date time picker like this

```
    $("#marketDate").datetimepicker({
        showSecond: true,
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss',
        duration: 'fast',
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true
     });
```

Comment: Can you post a reduced example code to help we in helping you?

Comment: i have edited the post with example code

Comment: My off the cuff first response is to get the author to assist with his code...

Comment: Could you write the versions of jQuery and jQuery UI you are using, as well as the jQuery UI CSS theme?

Comment: Sounds like a question you might wanna ask Mr Richardson instead … (after checking whether the original examples behave the same in IE 10/Win 8, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this on Windows 8 64-bit in IE-10 with all normal Standards and IE10 mode set. Please verify that your IE10 settings doesn't have Quirks mode enabled nor a lower version of IE enabled. This can sometimes get changed when testing using the Developer Tools. Hit F12 to get the Developer Tools bar in the bottom. Below are my screenshots of what it looks like for me based on his example on his website, as well as what my IE10 is set to.

[image: Working Example]

[image: IE10 Mode is set]

[image: Standards mode as normal]

You are only mentioning what you see, but say you are using it in production code... did you get any messages from clients about it not working? Otherwise it could just be your system.

Lastly, as recommended in the comments, asking the developer is your first best bet to see why you might have a special case. Perhaps something else in your production code is interfering with the code and causing it to act differently in IE10. Hard to tell without further testing or a URL with live code to debug.

Comment: It may seem sort of obvious, but I also recommend you're using the most up-to-date version of his jQuery plugin. Also, make sure it works with your version of jQuery if you updated that and didn't update his code, or the opposite, maybe you updated his code to the newest and didn't update jQuery. Just more suggestions with the little info available.